# Android layout and checkbox

Tags: java, android

I'm working on an Android app, I have a layout that contains a `CheckBox`.

I wonder if I can access my `CheckBox` from the Java code and perform actions like checking.
I have the `CheckBox`'s resource id.

I forgot to mention that the checkbox and layout are created in java code,

I try it :

```
CheckBox ceb = (CheckBox)findViewById(arrListInt.get(i));
ceb.setChecked(true);
```

But the checkbox is not checked

Comment: Of course you can. Otherwise, it would be useless. What have you tried?

Comment: Your code seems alright. Please show your full activity code.

Comment: It has a lot of code, I'll explain more, I try to check some checbox (must be verified for each checbox), when you select an item in a spinner of my application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually how far i know you can access every View of our layout from the java code. And Access means full access. You can change their properties as you like.
The only thing that you will need is the "id".
Then just use the method

```
findViewById(R.id.your_id);
```

and then cast it to appropriate type.

Comment: thank you, I found my problem, my code is before the setContentView  so it is not work

Answer (score 3):

You should try this way:

```
CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.your_cb_ID);

    cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(buttonView.isChecked()==true){
                // Checkbox checked true
            } else {
                // Checkbox checked false
            }
        }
    });
```

Where : your_cb_ID is your CheckBox View ID

Answer (score 2):

try this :

```
CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkboxid);

if(cb.isChecked())
{
//do your work
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this can be achieved. If you have a reference to your `CheckBox` you can call the methods of the [`Checkable`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Checkable.html) interface: `setChecked(boolean)`, `isChecked()` and `toggle()`.